# Use 32-bit webBrowser Control in Any-CPU WPF Application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, 64-bit, browser

I am writing a VB.Net WPF application that needs to display HTML content and websites. I am doing this using the webBrowser control. The application takes a significant performance hit running under x86 and I would really like to keep it set to Any-CPU. However the webBrowser controls need to be 32bit so they can run flash. So is there any way of achieving this? Running the 32-bit webBrowser in a 64bit process, or some alternative control that will manage this and allow me to load HTML from a string and a URL?

Thanks for your help, and sorry I have not set this question out better, I have a killer headache right now.

Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you **cannot mix 32 bit and 64 bit code in the same Windows process**.

Maybe you should **investigate why your 32-bit application takes a performance it**. Unless you work with really large amounts of data the need the increased 64-bit address space, t**here is no reason a 32-bit application should be significantly slower**. As an example, have a look at Rico Mariani's blog posts explaining why Visual Studio 2010 is only 32-bit.

Comment: I feared as much. I am not working with huge amounts of data but I have quite a few (as many as 45) threads running. I know this is not good practice but I need to keep user-created elements of my application (kind of like widgets) running separately. I am assuming this is what causes the performance hit I get. It is just a case of getting some lag when dragging some controls around compared to none. Thanks for your answer. I will have a look and see if I have any really big bits of data hanging around anywhere that might cause the slowdown as well.